# Add "Your Question has been posted" notification

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, notifications

**Problem**

In [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2215/whats-the-secret-to-getting-posted/2223#2223), the question asker brought up a good point:

> There's no external notification that your question was successfully posted.

**Feature Request**: Add an orange bar to the top of the screen that 'pops up' when your question has been successfully posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you post a question, I could have sworn it took you to your question (proving that it got posted).

Comment: Yes, it does    .

Comment: Yeah, I think that this is all the indication that's needed.

Comment: Kyle: I agree...If you can't tell something's been posted after you've been transported to the page, I'm not sure how much an extra notification is going to help.

Comment: `lol                         `